# Is using Page's section scrolling good for UX?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, accessibility, touch-screen, usability-study

A designer is insisting on using this effect on a website like this

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

You must have seen this kind of interaction on some other websites.

In Mobile screen it's surely not usable because we can't show the content of single section full screen on mobile as that content would be too much for small screen as mobile device has small height than desktop to show the content. So for example if mobile device viewport height is 420px and we have content which doesn't fit in 420px height whole content of the section won't be visible

Before using it, I wanted to ask UX experts here that is there any pros and cons of this type of interaction.

Comment: could you please be a little more specific about the worries you have regarding mobile?

Comment: don't break my mousewheel. Seriously I consider these interactions more style over substance, as a user, I know I want to scroll but you are forcing me not to or to scroll in stages or watch a flashy animation beforehand. Its a nice way to annoy repeat visitors.

Comment: @DasBeasto Hiding things from mobile is not a solution in my opinion. http://www.whatdomobileuserswanttodo.com/

Comment: They can work on mobile. But if the issue is that have you too much content, then I'd argue this type of site isn't the best to begin with even on desktop. These types of sites are meant more for quick power-point-ish bullet points--not content heavy pages.

Comment: @da01 it can only work on mobile if we we have single column content. If we have 2 column content like app screenshot on left side and its description on right and in mobile screen both will be stacked one over another and therefore can't be fit on mobile viewport

Comment: @JitendraVyas sure. Like I said, if you have that much content, this isn't the right design.

Comment: Yes but in powerpoint we can have and image and text side by side so I think we can't compare this case even to that in my opinion. Also most the time we make presentations in laptops or desktops.

Answer (score 4):

Scrolling pattern and navigation largely depends on the information architecture and content strategy of your website. The page scroll UI pattern has been largely used to showcase features of a product and I think it has been misused in this way. In most cases, the features are not peers but are related/dependent on each other.

It seems page section scrolling on web evolved from the page control UI in iOS.

> The iOS HIG suggests that page control is designed for apps in which
>   each view is a peer of every other view and that it should **NOT** be
>   used to display views in a *hierarchy or other complex arrangement.*

Contrary to this, it's bad UX when page section scroll is being used for primary navigation in which there's hierarchy/relation between the pages. It forces users to jump from page to page if the information has hierarchical arrangement. In your second example, the page control dots are being used as navigation indicators. A **[recent article](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/4-ios-rules-break/)** on NN/g discussed that these dots are commonly overlooked by users and should never be used for key functionality.

There's a cross-over of UI patterns from mobile to web and some of them are becoming anti-patterns. ([like using hamburger icon as main navigation on desktop sites](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/)). The page scroll pattern has also crossed over in not so desirable manner.

Answer (score 0):

There's an old UX tenet about leaving the user in control. The second link you posted, the one page scroll link, takes control away from the user. On top of that it hijacks normal/expected browser behavior.

Without knowing the specific details of this particular site and use case I can't say it's good or bad but based on what I wrote above I'd say it's highly suspect.

Comment: Just to be complete, this is referring to [Shneiderman's "Eight Golden Rules of Interface Design"](http://faculty.washington.edu/jtenenbg/courses/360/f04/sessions/schneidermanGoldenRules.html): **#7** Support internal locus of control.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out, under most circumstances, this behaviour is not suitable for web content.

### So when would you use this style of navigation?

- When you have limited content that should be viewed sequentially *and*
- You're dealing with a fixed (or easily controlled) viewing screen dimensions *and*
- User would not use mouse scrolling as primary navigation controls

### Examples

- Showing product information on a kiosk screen

  - Kiosk screens are all similar sizes or have easily controlled aspect ratio to ensure all content shows up correctly on the screen
  - Kiosk screens can also act as digital sign boards, in which, you want full screen visuals to attract people to the screen
  - Sequential ordering of content is helpful for telling a story about the product
  - There's no mouse scrolling on a touch screen.
- Powerpoint replacement

  - Presenting fullscreen slides in sequential order
  - Presentation format naturally limits amount of content per slide
  - User is "driving" the presentation, so paging control and not mouse scrolling is important